# Any tips for dealing with AI rockets effectively?

Tags: frozen-synapse

The AI's use of rockets in this game is infuriating! I often find that I have to just keep trying things that seem relatively absurd to avoid being blown to bits or hang out in an open area (where I'm easy prey for machine gunners/ and snipers) to avoid getting killed by them.

Any tips on how to deal with those pesky rockets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Receiving rocket fire is always a pain, but against the AI (in the single player campaign) it is particularly awkward because the AI usually outnumbers you with a lot of supporting units.

A few bits of advice against rockets are:

- Try and eliminate rocketeers early, they are very dangerous (as you've presumably noticed).
- Be afraid of walls and cover, they are murderous.
- Rocketeers cannot hurt a unit stood out of explosion radius of objects, ie a unit out in the open.
- Stand back from cover. If you're 20m away (or whatever is out of blast radius) from cover and the enemy is 100m away then you still get the cover bonus.
  [How exactly does cover work in Frozen Synapse?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23811/how-exactly-does-cover-work-in-frozen-synapse) is useful for more information here.
- Rocketeers can only fire about every ~5 seconds - so once per turn - if they fire at the end of one turn you have several seconds to charge them down at the start of the next.
- Units can shoot through explosions, so if you stand back from a wall that gets hit your units may be able to fire at the rocketeer through the newly created gap.
- Units can run through explosions, which can be useful for catching people off-guard. The damage is only for the instant the rocket hits, the visible explosion has no effect. You can create a path through a wall (that you expect to be destroyed) using a <kbd>Shift</kbd>+`Click` when placing a waypoint, if it's not destroy the unit will just "stop" in the wall.

And I'm afraid that's all I can offer, the rest is down to you finding a way to out-manoeuvre and out-smart your opponent. But do note that the single player campaign is *intentionally* difficult. At least I've seen the developers reference this on their Twitter stream a few times before, I'll hunt for an example of this later, if I've got the time.

Comment: Awesome -- I had basically come up with most of those, but the reminder about being able to stand back from cover is particularly helpful.

Comment: Also, for those cases where the AI rockets start in a small room, you can sometimes get them to kill themselves by grouping all of your units behind a solid wall of that room. (The rockets don't have a better shot, so they decide to open one up, and may kill themselves or other allies in the process.)